# Python Pandas : How to get days difference from first date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to find the date difference grouping by ID and using the first date by ID as the starting point.

Input

```
ID Date
1  1/1/2020
1  1/1/2020
1  1/5/2020
2  1/1/2020
2  1/3/2020
2  1/10/2020
```

Output

```
ID Date       DateDiff
1  1/1/2020   0
1  1/1/2020   0
1  1/5/2020   4
2  1/1/2020   0
2  1/3/2020   2
2  1/10/2020  9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `groupby.transform` and `first`.

```
df['DateDiff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) #to work with datetime object
df['DateDiff'] = (df['DateDiff']-
                  df['DateDiff'].groupby(df['ID']).transform('first')).dt.days

print(df)

   ID       Date  DateDiff
0   1   1/1/2020         0
1   1   1/1/2020         0
2   1   1/5/2020         4
3   2   1/1/2020         0
4   2   1/3/2020         2
5   2  1/10/2020         9
```

Comment: probably `min` and not `first`? unless it's known to already be sorted